# Sifting Property of Convolution

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, convolution

This is going to be a dumb question, but I can't figure it out, so here goes

$ f(t)\quad \bigotimes \quad \delta \quad (t\quad -\quad { t }_{ o }) $  =  $\int { f(\tau )\delta (t\quad -\quad { t }_{ o }\quad -\quad \tau ) } \quad =\quad f(t\quad-\quad { t }_{ o })$

but when I try to do the convolution integral, I get

$ \int { f(\tau) \delta (t\quad -\quad (\tau \quad -\quad { t }_{ o }) } \quad d\tau  $

which is not quite the same thing. What's my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a convolution is of the form:

$$ (f * g)(t) = \int f(\tau)g(t - \tau) d\tau $$

In your case, the function $g(t) = \delta (t - t_0)$.  We then get

$$ (f * g)(t) = \int f(\tau) \delta((t - \tau) - t_0) d\tau = \int f(\tau) \delta(t - t_0 - \tau) d \tau$$

Using the fact that $g(t - \tau) = \delta((t - \tau) - t_0)$

Of course, the right hand term using properties of the $\delta$ function can be evaluated to $f(t - t_0)$.

Comment: Thanks. Told you it was a stupid question. I mixed up t and Tau which is why I was arriving at that answer. Thanks again